# UI Flickers every time I click a button which update states

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am relatively new to React. I am developing a generic weather app as a personal project. I has a button which when clicked shows the forecast of the next 7 days, it works absolutely fine.
Once the button is clicked, it changes its name to "Close the Forecast" and upon clicking, it clears out all the forecasts from the screen, it works but the screen flickers everytime I click the button.

I used TypeScript for the project(new to TypeScript as well).
I am using useStates to store my data

```
  const [loc, setLoc] = useState<string>();
  const [temp, setTemp] = useState<string>();
  const [err, setErr] = useState<string>("");
  const [icon, setIcon] = useState<string>("");
  const [cond, setCond] = useState<string>();
  const [next, setNext] = useState<any[]>([]);
```

I have also used state to store/manage the click to the button :

`const [isloading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);`

this is before the first click/Page load :

```
{!isloading && (
        <button
          className="rounded-full bg-sky-500/75 hover:bg-sky-500/100 px-5 py-3 my-5"
          onClick={forecastHandler}
        >
          See Next 7 Days Forecast
        </button>
      )}
```

above code then fetch the data from a weatherAPI and stores the data for future use.

once clicked, isloading turns to true.

here is the code after isloading turns to true:

```
 {isloading && (
        <button
          className="rounded-full bg-sky-500/75 hover:bg-sky-500/100 px-5 py-3 my-5"
          onClick={isLoadingHandler}
        >
          Close The Forecast
        </button>
      )}
```

this is what happens when you click the above button (clears out all the states assossiated with next 7days forecasts :

```
const isLoadingHandler = () => {
    setIsLoading(false);
    setIcon("");
    setCond("");
    setNext([]);
  };
```

But this leads to flickering of the screen, which is not what I desired.

Comment: May have something to do with the fact how many different states you're using. Are they really necessary?

Comment: Hi @MikeSzyndel, each of the states holds a different value, other than [next,setNext] which holds an array. I might use just two states that hold just current and forecast data, but at this moment, I am just looking around and going through completing the project.